# Solving the probability for sample size

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

I'm given a sample data of heights of customers for a coffee shop in **previous week**.

```
y = (1.78,1.65,1.62,1.84,1.75,1.85,1.52,1.55)
```

The **mean** of the dataset is **1.695** and the **standard deviation** is **0.1279509**.

I've used R to generate a few probabilities for certain scenarios:

For customers of height $<1.5$m,

```
P(X<1.5) = 0.05163023
```

For customers of height $>1.8$m,

```
P(X>1.8) = 0.1901652
```

For customers of height $> 1.5$m and $< 1.65$m,

```
P(1.5 < X < 1.65) = 0.3018355
```

For customers of height > 1.65m and < 1.8m,

```
P(1.65 < X < 1.8) = 0.456369
```

I have a question which I couldn't seem to figure out.

"If the coffee shop receives **10 customers in one day**, what is the **probability** that **none** of them will be **1.65m or taller**."

I'm given a sample data of customers in previous week but the question states "10 customers in one day". I was wondering how would we calculate the probability if so?

I attempted something like:

```
P(X>= 1.65) = 0.6465343
```

But it doesnt seem like I'm using the "10" as the question stated, and the probability above is based on the data for previous week not on the day.

Would like some help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, your answer $\mathbb{P}(X \ge 1.65) \approx 0.65$ is correct, however this indicates the probability of *one* costumer to be $1.65$m or taller. To answer your original question, let $X_1, \dots, X_{10}$ be the heights of customers and the probability of our interest is 
$$
\mathbb{P}(X_{1} < 1.65, \dots, X_{10} < 1.65) = \mathbb{P}(X_1 < 1.65)^{10} \approx 0.35^{10} \approx 0.0000276,
$$ 
assuming independence of these customers.

Comment: hi, the solution you came up with is for customer 1.65m or taller but i think you missed out on the *none* in the original question. So in this case, do i take 1- 0.35^10 to obtain the probability that none of the customer falls in the range of 1.65m or taller? Also, why would it be ^10 instead of *10? Would appreciate some explanation.

Comment: No, I’ve calculated the probability that ***none*** of the customers is $1.65$m or taller. Your question says that all of them are less than $1.65$m is exactly what I’ve calculated. Why it’s ${\cdot}^{10}$, because the union of independent events become a product (not the sum).